# Attributed String

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

[a text that has some part with yellow background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgLcQ.png)I need some padding to left and right of yellow colored text and need the label "3" to be center..I am using attributed text for it.can anyone help me on this.Below is the code i am using.Attaching screenshot as well.

```
string CardTileText = "3 Shared Documents";
NSAttributedString decoratedText = CardTileText.GetAttributedStringFromHtml("#ffe601","3");


  public static NSAttributedString GetAttributedStringFromHtml(this string source, UIColor color, string identifier)
        {
            var atts = new UIStringAttributes();
            UIFont newConnFont = UIFont.FromName("NotoSans-Bold", 16);
            NSRange range = GetRangeFor(source, identifier);
            NSNumber offset = 5;

            NSMutableParagraphStyle para = new NSMutableParagraphStyle
            {
                Alignment = UITextAlignment.Left
            };
            NSMutableAttributedString attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(source, atts);
            attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.BackgroundColor, color, range);
            attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Black, range);
            attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, newConnFont, range);
            attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.KerningAdjustment, offset, range);
            attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle, para, range);

            return attributedString;
        }

        static NSRange GetRangeFor(string source, string substring)
        {
            var range = new NSRange
            {
                Location = source.IndexOf(substring, StringComparison.Ordinal),
                Length = substring.Length
            };
            return range;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only solution is that set `offset`(which is used on `KerningAdjustment`) with a proper value.

Here is the comparison

- offset = 0.5

[image]

- offset = 10

[image]

Comment: But that doesn't give me the 3 value to be center..there is less padding to left side

Comment: AFAIK , no way to center the single value, since  `ParagraphStyle` works on the whole string not part of it .